# Why should central bank intervention cause inverted yield curve to be less effective as a recession signal?

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, yield

Pimco's new CIO Dan Ivascyn believes that the inverted yield curve has become less effective as a signal of impending recession.

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-06-22/pimco-s-ivascyn-says-next-inverted-yield-curve-may-be-different

> Some see it as an almost surefire economic law: an inverted yield
>   curve, when long-term bonds yield less than short-term debt, signals a
>   coming recession.
>
> That may not hold true in today’s world of unprecedented central-bank
>   economic intervention, according to Dan Ivascyn, Pacific Investment
>   Management Co.’s group chief investment officer.

Mr Ivascyn, being CIO of the world's largest bond fund manager, should know his stuff. However, I don't understand why. In fact, I thought the opposite should be true. **The inverted yield curve should be more, not less, effective as a recession indicator thanks to central bank intervention**. Here is my reasoning. Short-term interest is artificially low today thanks to central bank intervention. Therefore, it is harder for long-term interest rates to go lower than short-term interest rates because short-term rates are already artificially low. So, if an inverted yield curve still happens despite artificially low short-term rates, wouldn't it be a stronger signal of recession? What did I miss out? Please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's talking about central bank intervention in the longer maturities, not the short end.  The Fed bought a lot of long dated Treasuries, which helped flatten the curve.  Hence an inverted curve may reflect all the securities bought by the Fed.

Comment: Looking globally, we've always got BoJ directly targeting bond yields (by keeping 10-year bond yield at 0), so you really can't draw much inference using conventional lens.